# Android custom list view with checkbox issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a list view that is similar to gmail inbox view .

the xml layout for the custom view is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_subject_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/firstText"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:text=""
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/secondText" />

<CheckBox
    style="?android:attr/starStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:id="@+id/star" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/details"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/thirdText" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/details"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/duration"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/thirdText" />
```

Now what i want is when a user clicks on the message it should be marked as read, and if he selects the star (checkbox) then it should be marked as favorite . so the problem with me is that when he selects the checkbox it is marked as read and the checkbox is shown as selected, and when i uncheck it, it shows as unread, i have handled the things in the backend.

the code for the same is :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); 
    TextView details = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.details); 
    TextView expiry = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration);
    TextView type = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.type);
    CheckBox fav = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.star);

    final MessageDTO message = data.get(position);
    title.setText(message.getSubject());
    if(message.getExpiryDate() != null) {
        expiry.setText("Expires On : " + 
                new SimpleDateFormat(getContext()
                        .getString(R.string.detailsDisplayDateTimeFormat))
        .format(message.getExpiryDate()));          
    }
    details.setText(message.getMessage());
    type.setText(message.getType());

    if(message.isFavorite()) {
        fav.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        fav.setChecked(false);
    }
    if(message.isRead()) {
        vi.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.message_read));
        title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        details.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    } else {
        vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        details.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    }
    vi.setClickable(true);
    vi.setFocusable(true);
    vi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            messageRepository.markMessageRead(message.getId());
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MessageDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("com.xyz.android.msgId", message.getId());
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            if(message.isFavorite() && !cb.isChecked()) {
                messageRepository.markMessageFav(message.getId(), 0);
            } else if(!message.isFavorite() && cb.isChecked()) {
                messageRepository.markMessageFav(message.getId(), 1);
            }
        }
    });
    return vi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling onclickListner on your convertView i.e "vi" set onclickListner on "TextView title".

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use preference to have state of checkbox checked or unchecked and do the rest according by reading the value back from saved preference values

Comment: neither using preference can solve my problem stated , will it .. ?